# How to register Umbraco RenderMvcControllers in global asax

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, umbraco7, global-asax

I am trying to use `RenderMvcController` and `SurfaceController` with dependency injection but it doesn't work.

```
public class SupplierRenderMvcController : RenderMvcController
{
    public HomeRenderMvcController(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }
}

public class SupplierController : SurfaceController
{
    public SupplierController(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Umbraco's controllers are registered in in `Global.asax`:

```
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(UmbracoApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UmbracoApplication).Assembly);
```

I have api controllers using IoC with no problem in other projects of the same solution.

The above controllers are in the main project of the solution though.

This is my full `Global.asax` of the main project:

```
public class MvcApplication : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        RegisterIoCContainer();
    }

    public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
    }

    private void RegisterIoCContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(UmbracoApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UmbracoApplication).Assembly);

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly‌​());

        builder.RegisterModule<WebApiConfig>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    }
}
```

`MembershipService` is registered within `WebApiConfig`:

```
public class WebApiConfig : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddMediatR(this.GetType().Assembly);

        builder.RegisterType<MembershipService1>().As<IMembershipService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"If you do not register a controller, then ASP.NET will try to create the controller, but if it doesn't have an empty constructor, you'll get a YSOD."*, source: [Using-Ioc in umbraco 7](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Using-Ioc/index-v7). From your error I would assume that the controllers are not registered. I would investigate if they really are in the executing assembly.

Comment: I'm not sure how am I supposed to check it? @Marta As far as I know this should register `RenderMvcController` as they inherit from `Controller` : `builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(UmbracoApplication).Assembly);` Adding explicitly `builder.RegisterType<MyRenderMvcController>().As<IRenderMvcController>();` doesn't make any difference either